# link client profile .net dll with non-client profile .dll?

Tags: .net

I develop a .dll which uses .net 4.0 client profile (CP). However, I also have a .dll which I would like to link with my .dll and that another .dll (DotNetOpenAuth) is not compatible with client profile as it uses System.Web.

I know you can't reference non-CP .dll with CP-compatible project. The question is how can I do this :) I know many things are not possible at first glance but with some tweaking?..

The thing I don't understand why the compiler just doesn't give me the warning that my project which targets CP links non-CP .dll. If it worked this way, I would be able to have CP-compatible .DLL which would work in most cases unless the feature which utilizes DotNetOpenAuth gets called.

In brief, I want to move CP-compatibility check from compile time to runtime. This is because my .dll has many features and most people will never use that part which requires DotNetOpenAuth. Those folks which need DotNetOpenAuth will have to use full .net framework. But this must not be the show-stopper for others.

I mean something like AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute which allows you to move some compile time checks to runtime.

I don't want to maintain two separate versions of the .dll (one for web apps and another for client profile) as it adds complexity for the users which .dll to select. I'd prefer to keep things simple.

Of course, there is a method of dynamic loading of a .dll through reflection but this requires quite high privileges from the running code (in case of web apps they probably won't have enough privileges for this).